# What does :submodules => true mean in a CocoaPod Podspec?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods

**TL ; DR :**

What does `CocoaPods` do if you set `:submodules` (part of `spec.source`) as `true`?

**Full Version:**

My previous project structure looked like

```
Project
Linked To --> Core static library (submodule added as a subproject)
            --> Linked To --> several dependent submodules (files added within subproject)
```

I'm now in the process of transitioning to `CocoaPods` for dependency management.

My new (transitional) structure looks like

```
Project
--> Depends on Core CocoaPod and few other CocoaPods
     --> Core depends on several open-source libraries
     --> Core also depends on a few submodules (in process of converting these)
```

I've seen other projects (e.g. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/AFNetworking/2.1.0/AFNetworking.podspec)) specify their `source` like this:

`s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git', :tag => "2.1.0", :submodules => true }`

What does `CocoaPods` do if you pass `:submodules` as `true` as in this example? Is this the right setting for this use case?

I can't seem to find this documented anywhere on [CocoaPods.org](http://cocoapods.org/).

Answer (score 2):

This is to do with git repositories that have submodules ([See Git Submodules for more information on them](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)). Normally when you clone a git repository you need to do something like:

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

to pull down the submodules which the git repository depends on (e.g. if the git library has a reference to another git library it could add it as a submodule instead of adding the files to its own versioning - meaning the submodule could update and the git library would have access to the latest version automatically)

I don't know exactly what cocoapods does as part of the git clone process but I imagine it would run these 2 commands after cloning the repository to ensure all the submodule dependancies are valid.

FYI this command does inits and updates all submodules and any submodules they depend on - so it's is probably what cocoapods uses

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This change was introduced in 0.12.0: (see [changelog](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/fde871739a91b7324220962a68943ca4e37bce74/CHANGELOG.md#0120))

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 Appreciate the feedback, Rob. I'm going to need to look into this further though. I'm not sure why `AFNetworking` would need `:submodules => true` - it doesn't appear to have submodules in the repo - and my project, which does have existing submodules, isn't setup correctly with this parameter set... most likely doing something wrong, I'm sure... :/ Let me know if you come across docs on this though... :D

Comment: Is it possible to have a look through the cocoapods source code and see if you can find what they do? I know the code is Ruby but it shouldn't be too hard to understand - I will see if i can find out where that flag is checked/handled

Comment: It appears this issue is related to the :submodules flag https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/442

Answer (score 1):

It means the pod contains git submodules, however if you use your pod via a git url in your Podfile it has no effect. In that case you again need to specify `:submodules => true` in the Podfile.

If AFNetworking specifies this param but actually has no git submodules then it must simply be a mistake.

If you depend on other pods then use the dependencies param instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, I have no means to verify if this is correct or not... This question is very old, and in general, not very relevant for my project or, in my opinion, the vast majority of projects anymore... on this note, I may simply close this question entirely, depending on whether community takes action on this within next few days or so...

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about that and I was suffering from the problem which I have now put in the updated answer.

Comment: Hi @malhal do you have more info about that? How you solved it?

Comment: Sorry I don’t have any more info