# How to import an iOS framework as a git submodule, when the framework has external dependencies

Tags: ios, frameworks, git-submodules, clean-architecture

You have the main Project "App" with its own Git repo; you separate out the model into a separate framework project "AppKit" again with its own Git repo. "AppKit" is imported into "App" as a Git submodule & everything is merry.

If "AppKit" has external dependencies -- let's say managed by CocoaPods, the typical import-as-submodule fails since "AppKit"s dependencies are not satisfied by the "App".
I want to know if there is any way to achieve this while importing the "AppKit" as Git submodule. Can it be done?

I am aware there are several straightforward solutions to this -

1. Make "AppKit" a "Carthage"able framework & import it
2. Make & import "AppKit" as a CocoaPod.

I just wanted a definitive answer (in case it cannot be done as Git Submodule) so I can move on.

Context: Pursuit of the ideal solution to managing a multi-project App (so other ideas / opinions welcome)

Making the question clearer --

Can an iOS framework project be imported as a Git Submodule if it has dependencies of its own.
If the sub-dependencies are --

1. Cocoapods
2. Carthage
3. Git submodule

Comment: I will accept a negative answer as well, it just needs be definitive.

Comment: My suspicions are -
i. Can not be done
ii. Can be done (if I commit the sub-dependency frameworks in the framework project)
iii. Can be done (Not sure how)

If it can be done, please mention how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`git submodule`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) itself, as part of the Git commands, has no notion of CocoaPod dependencies.

The Cocoa dependency manager itself does have notion of such dependencies, declared as submodules, and managed as such [since CocoadPod 0.1.20](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/fde871739a91b7324220962a68943ca4e37bce74/CHANGELOG.md#0120) (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21790437/6309)).

That means: if AppKit itself is a CocoaPod, it can declared its own dependencies as Git submodules, and CocoaPod will manage (load) them, provided your own project ask for said dependencies, using  `:submodules => true`

```
s.source   = { :git => 'https://github.com/<you>/AppKit.git', :tag => "2.1.0", :submodules => true }
```

So:

> Can an iOS framework project be imported as a Git Submodule if it has dependencies of its own.

If that project is imported as a CocoaPod, the Cocoa dependency manager can take care of the imported project dependencies if those are git submodules.
But if the imported project is just a Git submodule (without being declared/imported as a CocoaPod), Git itself would not managed said dependencies as "CocoaPod" (since it knows nothing about XCode project dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There's no problem if the AppKit itself is a CocoaPod or Carthagable framework. (Carthage would make more sense in case my own project is not using cocoapods). But I did not know about CocoaPod managing its own dependencies via git submodule (that's good to know). 
So I suppose the answer in my case is it can not be done (that was my suspicion). I'll accept the answer before the bounty expires.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, if you can edit your answer to match it, that'd be super. Thanks.